# under which scenario AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonRouteConfigurationChange can be called

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

I have been investigating AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason notification.
One of them is

```
AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonRouteConfigurationChange
```

According to Apple document:
[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonRouteConfigurationChange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosessionroutechangereason/avaudiosessionroutechangereasonrouteconfigurationchange)

The set of input and output ports has not changed, but their configuration has—for example, a port’s selected data source has changed.

It is not very clear that under which scenario AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonRouteConfigurationChange can be called. If someone could make an example what a port's selected data source has changed meaning?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for the 'Doc' answer as well, but I can also provide some example. After phone call ended I received AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded notification and just after it this one:

```
{   
AVAudioSessionRouteChangePreviousRouteKey = "<AVAudioSessionRouteDescription: 0x1c001e380, \ninputs = (null); \noutputs = (\n    \"<AVAudioSessionPortDescription: 0x1c001e4d0, type = Speaker; name = G\\U0142o\\U015bnik; UID = Speaker; selectedDataSource = (null)>\"\n)>";    
AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey = 8;
}
```

and new Route was:

```
<AVAudioSessionRouteDescription: 0x1c401de70, 
inputs = (
    "<AVAudioSessionPortDescription: 0x1c401dac0, type = MicrophoneBuiltIn; name = iPhone Mikrofon; UID = Built-In Microphone; selectedDataSource = Bottom>"
); 
outputs = (
    "<AVAudioSessionPortDescription: 0x1c401df10, type = Speaker; name = G\U0142o\U015bnik; UID = Speaker; selectedDataSource = (null)>"
)>
```

So it looks like selected data source for microphone changed from null to bottom.